# wagtail.search.backends.base.OrderByFieldError: Cannot sort search results with field "page_ptr". Please add index.FilterField('page_ptr') to Model

Tags: wagtail, wagtail-admin

I'm getting error below when trying to both search and order queryset in wagtail admin.

```
wagtail.search.backends.base.OrderByFieldError: Cannot sort search results with field "page_ptr". Please add index.FilterField('page_ptr') to Article.search_fields.
```

I've already added `index.FilterField('page_ptr')` to my model, but still getting that error. I can see it it search fields of my model:

```
 ...
 <SearchField: short_description>,
 <wagtail.search.index.RelatedFields at 0xffff922eb730>,
 <wagtail.search.index.RelatedFields at 0xffff922eb5b0>,
 <wagtail.search.index.RelatedFields at 0xffff922eb490>,
 <FilterField: page_ptr>]
```

Using `wagtail==2.16.3`